# C#, Metro, Stream Socket, SSL Untrusted Host, Squid

Tags: c#, ssl, microsoft-metro, squid, stream-socket-client

I need your help one more time.

I can't get how to successfully establish a StreamSocket connection from Metro application to **untrusted root certificate** host.
I'm connecting like this:

```
await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("_UNTRUSTED_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_"), "_SSL_PORT_", SocketProtectionLevel.Ssl);
```

And it fails :(

I can't establish a plain HTTP connection because of the host restriction.

Some say that I need to make a proxy server that will forward SSL queries to that untrusted host and which will mark this connection as **trusted**.
But how to do it? I didn't get it for now :(
I'm using Squid on my CentOS web-server and did this to squid.conf:

```
acl TrustedHosts url_regex _UNTRUSTED_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_
sslproxy_cert_error allow TrustedHosts
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
```

I need StreamSocket, because I must read to and write from the socket to make some valuable actions.

If anyone can help me with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by modifying the Control of the StreamSocket that way :

```
_streamSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
_streamSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
```

ChainValidationResult contains multiple options, choose the one best suited for you.